# Can't Access MetaData API From Public Sites Because Of Null Session Id. Any Workaround?

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, metadata-api

I couldn't access MetaData API from public force.com site because of the null session id for public sites.

I had a look at some Salesforce documentation and found that the session id is always null for public sites.

Does this mean that MetaData API access from Public Site is not possible?

Has anyone,ever, successfully invoked metadata API from public sites?

Comment: It is possible, you just need to source a valid Session ID through another method. Generally speaking, is it a good idea to expose a session with access to the Metadata API via a public site? Whatever approach you take you will need to be careful to keep that Session ID secret.

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for you answer Daniel Ballinger . Can you please suggest the valid method for getting Session Id for this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are wide variety of methods to access session id. We can use the Salesforce access token in place of session id to access this API.

Web Server Flow , Username Password Flow or User Agent flow can be implemented to access the Salesforce Access Token (Session Id)